# Php arrays fetching and calculating

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays, function

here is my code

```
for ($i=0; $i<$Percentile["Parameter_length"]; $i++)
{
  $parameters.="Eqt_Param".$i."=".$Percentile["Eqt_Param".$i]; 
  $Per_Wtg.="Per_Wtg".$i."=".$Percentile["Eqt_Param".$i]/100;
}
```

if i display(echo $Per_Wtg;) $per_wtg outside for loop i get

```
'Per_Wtg0=0.03 Per_Wtg1=0 Per_Wtg2=0 Per_Wtg3=0'
```

well i have one more code

```
for ($i=0; $i<$Percentile["min_length"]; $i++)
{
    $min.="Eqt_Min".$i."=".$Percentile["Eqt_Min".$i];
}
```

if i display(echo $min;) $min outside for loop i get

```
'Eqt_Min0=1.00Eqt_Min1=1.00Eqt_Min2=1.00Eqt_Min3=1.00'
```

but now i need display one more array variable

```
$Eqt_Sr0=($Per_Wtg0-$Eqt_Min0) ,
$Eqt_Sr1=($Per_Wtg1-$Eqt_Min1) , 
$Eqt_Sr2=($Per_Wtg2-$Eqt_Min2) , 
$Eqt_Sr3=($Per_Wtg3-$Eqt_Min3)
```

to make this i may have to take one more array `$Eqt_Sr`

but how to display this outside `for loop` anyways to fix this?

Comment: please take some time to format your code correctly, thanks!

Comment: k dear..sorry i was bit hurry ,,i will make sure it does not happen again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$Eqt_Sr = array();

for ($i=0; $i<$Percentile["Parameter_length"]; $i++)
{
  $parameters.="Eqt_Param".$i."=".$Percentile["Eqt_Param".$i]; 
  $Per_Wtg.="Per_Wtg".$i."=".$Percentile["Eqt_Param".$i]/100;

  /*Look the array $Eqt_Sr*/
  $Eqt_Sr[$i] = $Percentile["Eqt_Param".$i]/100;
}
```

Then:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$Percentile["min_length"]; $i++)
{
    $min.="Eqt_Min".$i."=".$Percentile["Eqt_Min".$i];

    // Add here
    $Eqt_Sr[$i] =  $Eqt_Sr[$i] - $Percentile["Eqt_Min".$i];
}
```

To display the array:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($Eqt_Sr); $i++){
   $output .= "Eqt_Sr".$i."=(".$Eqt_Sr[$i]."),";
}
```

Comment: Now you can use the $Eqt_Sr to display "$Eqt_Sr0=($Per_Wtg0-$Eqt_Min0)" using for

Comment: if i display $Eqt_Sr outside for loop it is displayed as `Array` :( how to fix this?

Comment: hmm k k .. can you also tell me one thing ... i want create variable `$Eqt_Min=Eqt_Min0+$Eqt_Min1+$Eqt_Min2+$Eqt_Min3` how to do that??

Comment: You can use 'for' again, but $output += $Eqt_min[$i]

Comment: Oh wait... if you used $output before, try to use $output2 ou another variable. The variable's names its just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is an absolute mess, and its impossible to tell what it is you are actually looking for, but I'll take a guess at it.

Not sure why you are using 'Parameter_length' and 'min_length' as you appear to expect them to always be the same value - But what happens if they are different?  My code below deals with the case of `min_length >= Parameter_length`, but not `min_length < Parmeter_length`

**script**

```
<?php

// Data assumed from inspection of original post
$Percentile = array
(
        'Eqt_Param0' => 3.00,
        'Eqt_Param1' => 0.00,
        'Eqt_Param2' => 0.00,

        'Parameter_length' => 3,

        'Eqt_Min0' => 1.00,
        'Eqt_Min1' => 1.00,
        'Eqt_Min2' => 1.00,

        'min_length' => 3,
);

$Parameters = array();
$Per_Wtg    = array();
$Eqt_Min    = array();
$Eqt_Sr     = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $Percentile['Parameter_length']; $i++)
{
    $param = $Percentile["Eqt_Param{$i}"];
    $wtg   = $param / 100;

    $Parameters[$i] = $param;
    $Per_Wtg[$i]    = $wtg;
}

// TODO What if 'min_length' != 'Parameter_length' ??
for ($i = 0; $i < $Percentile['min_length']; $i++)
{
    $param = $Percentile["Eqt_Param{$i}"];
    $min   = $Percentile["Eqt_Min{$i}"];

    $Eqt_Min[$i] = $min;
    $Eqt_Sr[$i]  = ( array_key_exists($i, $Parameters) ? $Parameters[$i] : 0 ) - $min;
}

print " Parameters => " . join(', ', $Parameters) . "\n";
print " Per_Wtg    => " . join(', ', $Per_Wtg   ) . "\n";
print " Eqt_Min    => " . join(', ', $Eqt_Min   ) . "\n";
print " Eqt_Sr     => " . join(', ', $Eqt_Sr    ) . "\n";
```

**output**

```
 Parameters => 3, 0, 0
 Per_Wtg    => 0.03, 0, 0
 Eqt_Min    => 1, 1, 1
 Eqt_Sr     => 2, -1, -1
```

Comment: thanks alot for trying dear... iam passing arrays through javascripts bcos its ajax page ... thats the reason it looks messy...